# much/very respected

Tags: adjectives, past-participles

[Fowler's Concise Dictionary of Modern English Usage, page 621](https://books.google.es/books?id=w2NjCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA621&dq=%22If%20we%20say%20a%20much%20respected%20politician%20we%20stress%20the%20process%2C%20whereas%20if%20we%20say%20a%20very%20respected%20politician%20we%20assess%20the%20effect.%22&hl=es&pg=PA621#v=onepage&q=%22If%20we%20say%20a%20much%20respected%20politician%20we%20stress%20the%20process,%20whereas%20if%20we%20say%20a%20very%20respected%20politician%20we%20assess%20the%20effect.%22&f=false)  reads

> If we say *a **much** respected politician* we stress the process, whereas
> *a very **respected** politician* assesses the effect.

What *process* and *effect* is the author referring to here?

Comment: The process of respecting and the resultant level of respect.

Comment: I'd challenge this ('respected' is more stative than is implied here), and argue they're closely synonymous. M-W gives 'adverbial' (adjective-modifier)  'much' and 'very' as synonyms; _much gratified_.  As in 'very/much impressed'.

Comment: @Jim Still, STRESS a process vs ASSESS its result, why?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman what would be the differences for **obliged** https://oed.com/oed2/00161398 (unlike **respected** https://oed.com/oed2/00204222)

Comment: I'd agree with Fowler that the two are different: "much respected" implies widely respected but not necessarily to a great degree (in terms of process, there is a lot of respecting but not a deep level of respect), while in contrast "very respected" implies a deep level of respect but possibly by fewer people (you could be very respected within a narrow or obscure field). Similarly. "much loved" means something similar to "popular", referring to someone the public are fond of, in contrast to "deeply loved" which means loved a great deal but not necessarily by many.

Comment: @StuartF _(
a
) The uses of **very** and **much** as
intensifying adverbs are for the most part complementary. Very
qualifies adjectives and adverbs (
very large, very slowly),
whereas much qualifies past participles that are used as
adjectives (
a much enlarged edition; They were much
criticized; a much enfeebled Soviet Union)._ LOVED http://oed.com/oed2/00136043, BELOVED http://oed.com/oed2/00020085

Comment: I can only give the comparison between this and the POSS-ing v ACC-ing analyses (ignoring the different registers): 'I remember his singing at the show' (stressing the durative performance) vs 'I remember him singing at the show' (stressing the event, treating it as punctive, yes or no). But I repeat, I disagree with there being different semantic emphases between _much_ and _very_ here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Regarding **LOVED**, OED contradicts itself.                                   
 **MUCH (adv)** 5. Combined: (a) with past pples., as in _much-abused, much-admired, much-criticized, **much-loved**_ https://oed.com/oed2/00152815. 
However, the entry for **loved** reads

**Adjective.** 1.a. In senses of the verb.; in attributive use now chiefly poet., exc. with prefixed adverb as _dearly-loved, **much-loved**_; ordinarily superseded by **beloved**. https://oed.com/oed2/00136043

Comment: In 'was much loved by ...' (cf 'was hard hit by') 'much' has to be an adverb within the passive construction. Note that 'very' is ungrammatical here.  But it's best to see prenominal 'much-loved' as an intensified (compound if hyphenated) adjective. OED is not always wonderful when it comes to POS assignation. Note that here, 'very' is idiomatic with 'respected', but not with other participial adjectives.